# how to get meter data from electricity meter with arduino with ir sensor

Tags: arduino

**Hardware:**

arduino mkr wan 1310

Electricity meter: MME DTZ541 three-phase meter

reading head: [Hichi TTL - IR reading head](https://www.amazon.de/Lesekopf-Leitung-Stromz%C3%A4hler-optisch-auslesen/dp/B0BPMVX4VW/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2IE0LDX6WEOVL&keywords=ttl%2Blesekopf&qid=1686003405&sprefix=ttl%2Blesekopf%2Caps%2C80&sr=8-3&th=1)

**Data:**

we should get constant data rate of 9600 baud from meter. Character encoding is in 8-N-1 format. The transmission protocol is based on the SML specification version 1.04.

**attempts made:**

[<IRremote.h>](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote) library only returns nonsense with the `IrReceiver.decodedIRData.decodedRawData` function (e.g. we never get the initial sequence 1B 1B 1B 1B)

the <SoftwareSerial.h> is not compatible with our arduion board

how do we get the current meter reading on the arduino with the hardware?

Comment: The so called IR reading head is misleading, it consists of a phototransistor (BPW 40) and a 1 kΩ pull-up resistor designed for connecting to one of the GPIO pins of the microcontroller to detect a blinking/pulse from some light source on the power meter as a counter. It has nothing to do with IR Remote, so of course it won't produce nonsense when you try to decode it as IR Remote protocol!

Answer (score 0):

with this hardware we can read it out with the following code and get the data as hex values ​​in the sml protocol. the reading head is connected to the rx tx pins.

```
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    Serial1.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N1); 
}

void loop() 
{
    if (Serial1.available()) 
    {  
        Serial.print(Serial1.read(),HEX);
    }
}
```